# Azure Point to Site random disconnection

Tags: azure

Has anyone used azure point to site vpn and has trouble with keep disconnecting randomly and unexpectedly, it does not give an error, but when I look into vpn network adapter log I got this at the time the connection drops

> **your routing table ActionPath = C:\Users####\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Cm\DDBD2EC9-C6B1-4735-922F-BEB3FE5A94CB\CMROUTE.DLL
>   ReturnValue = 0x0 [cmdial32]    18:19:09    13    Disconnect Event
>
>   CallingProcess = C:\WINDOWS\system32\CMMON32.EXE [CMMON32]    18:19:09
>   26    External Disconnect due to Lost Connection**

The azure VPN gateway does not report any issues.

Regards,
Joe

Comment: Do you still have this issue or did you already find a solution? We are also using the Azure VPN and some of the users have te same issue.